# Delete blanks in list created by Zip Function python

Tags: python, transpose

I'm trying to transpose data, and the zip function works perfectly. Except since it finds the longest list and applies it to every list I have through the loop, I end up with a lot of blanks.

This is my code:

```
Read_Data = inputdata.readlines()
Length_Data = len(Read_Data)
for a in range(Length_Data):
   split_data = Read_Data[a].split(',')

   zipper = zip(split_data)
   print zipper
```

Which gives me this output (this is just one example list from a much larger dataset):

```
[('Abagrotis alternata',), ('Bignoniaceae',), ('Cruciferae',), ('Ericaceae',), ('Fagaceae',), ('Juglandaceae',), ('Oleaceae',), ('Pinaceae',), ('Rosaceae',), ('Solanaceae',), ('',), ('',), ('',), ('',), ('',), ('',), ('',), ('',), ('',), ('',), ('',), ('',), ('',), ('',), ('',), ('',), ('',), ('',), ('',), ('',), ('',), ('',), ('',), ('',), ('',), ('',), ('',), ('',), ('',), ('',), ('',), ('',), ('',), ('',), ('',), ('',), ('',), ('',), ('',), ('',), ('',), ('',), ('',), ('',), ('',), ('',), ('\n',)]
```

I Have a lot of data that creates thousands of these list. Is there a way to delete the blanks or '' that occur in every list? Thanks for any help

I was doing it wrong so this is my example data

```
**Lep. Species**          **Column**       **Column**    **Column**   
Abablemma brimleyana        Algae               
Abagrotis alternata         Bignoniaceae    Cruciferae     Ericaceae          
Abagrotis anchocelioides    Ericaceae       Rosaceae            
Abagrotis brunneipennis     Rosaceae        Ericaceae           
Abagrotis cryptica          Rosaceae        Salicaceae          
Abagrotis cupida            Ericaceae       Rosaceae       Salicaceae       
Abagrotis magnicupida       Asteraceae      Caryophyllaceae
```

This is what I want my output to look like

```
**Lep. Species**             **Column**
Abablemma brimleyana            Algae   
Abagrotis alternata             Bignoniaceae
Abagrotis alternata             Cruciferae
Abagrotis alternata             Ericaceae
Abagrotis anchocelioides        Ericaceae
Abagrotis anchocelioides        Rosaceae
```

And so on.

I guess I need more help then I thought. Again thank you for any help

Comment: Are the empty strings always in the first position?

Comment: No its different for every list that is created

Comment: What does `zip` on `split_data` actually get you here? Why are zipping it at all?

Comment: `zip()` is normally used for *multiple lists*. You have only **one** input list, so all you are doing is wrap each element in a tuple. **Why are you zipping at all**?

Comment: Why not use the `csv` module for reading your file, and why not *loop directly* over the `Read_Data` list?

Comment: `reader = csv.reader(inputdata)`, then `for row in reader: # do something with each row`.

Comment: I'm trying to gather data together based on  one variable in one column. Then using the zip function to transpose the data from rows to columns.

Comment: Please provide an example of the input and describe what it represents.

Comment: @stagomight How do you represent "columns" and "rows" in your python code?

Comment: @stagomight: then your code is completely missing the plank.

Answer (score 6):

You can simply ignore/filter all the empty lines before passing to the `zip` built-in

```
zipper = zip(e for e in split_data if e)
```

**Explanation:**

```
e for e in split_data if e
```

Without the brackets, the above expression is a [generator expression](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/). A generator expression unlike a [list comprehension](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_comprehension#Python) (with the brackets), does not generates the entire list before passing to the `built-in` `zip`. So its just an [iterable](http://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-iterable) that `zip` iterates until it raises the exception [StopIteration](http://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html#exceptions.StopIteration)

The Expression is equivalent of the following Loop expression

```
result = []
for e in split_data:
    #Empty Check
    if e:
        result.append(e)
```

Comment: No e is just any variable. If your heart desires you can use any exotic name. Its just a generator expression to filter empty fields

Comment: I'm a beginner programmer and Would you mine explaining how that code works? again Thank you for the help

Comment: What this does is look at each element in `split_data`, and treat it as a boolean. Treating a list as a boolean returns false if it's empty, and so this is a slick way to only use non-empty lists. You can see the boolean nature of lists for yourself by doing `if not []: print 'hi'` or `if [3]: print 'bye'`. Both times something is printed, so we conclude that empty lists are `False` and non-empty lists are `True`. Thus, only non-empty lists are used.

Answer (score 3):

If you are trying to transpose the rows and columns of your CSV file, you are going about it the wrong way.

Use this instead:

```
import csv

by_column = zip(*csv.reader(inputdata))
```

`by_column` is now a list of lists, each nested list a column from your `inputdata` file object.

You are only zipping *one row at a time*, and you the empty string tuples are simply empty columns.

Looking at your update, all you really want to do is slice your rows:

```
import csv

with open('somefilename.csv', 'rb') as inputfile:
    reader = csv.reader(inputfile)
    for row in reader:
        row = row[:2]
        # process `row` further. It now only contains the first 2 columns.
```

Comment: This seems like the right way to do what I want. Could you explain further, now that I've shown my example data and output?

Comment: @stagomight: Updated. Next time, start with your actual task, not what you think might be the solution. :-)

Answer (score 1):

You could [`filter()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#filter) the tuples which have `""` in them.

```
>>> testList = [('Abagrotis alternata',), ('Bignoniaceae',), ('Cruciferae',), ('Ericaceae',), ('Fagaceae',), ('Juglandaceae',), ('Oleaceae',), ('Pinaceae',), ('Rosaceae',), ('Solanaceae',), ('',), ('',), ('',), ('',), ('',), ('',), ('',), ('',), ('',), ('',), ('',), ('',), ('',), ('',), ('',), ('',), ('',), ('',), ('',), ('',), ('',), ('',), ('',), ('',), ('',), ('',), ('',), ('',), ('',), ('',), ('',), ('',), ('',), ('',), ('',), ('',), ('',), ('',), ('',), ('',), ('',), ('',), ('',), ('',), ('',), ('',), ('\n',)]
>>> filter(lambda x: not "" in x, testList)
[('Abagrotis alternata',), ('Bignoniaceae',), ('Cruciferae',), ('Ericaceae',), ('Fagaceae',), ('Juglandaceae',), ('Oleaceae',), ('Pinaceae',), ('Rosaceae',), ('Solanaceae',), ('\n',)]
```

**Lists are iterable in Python.**

You don't have to do `for i in range(len(...))` you could just reduce your code to

```
Read_Data = inputdata.readlines()
for a in Read_Data:
   #...
```

Also, `readlines()` reads the whole file into the memory, why not iterate over the file instead?

```
for a in f:
    #...
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe that you misunderstand how the `zip` function works. It takes **multiple lists** and returns a list of tuples. For example,

```
zipper = zip(["a", "b", "c"], [1, 2, 3])
print zipper
```

will output

> [("a", 1), ("b", 2), ("c", 3)]

You are using `zip` with only a single list. So the result is a list of tuples which each have only a single element.

I suggest that you don't use `zip` to solve your original problem to transpose columns and rows of data. You need to figure out a way to represent those columns and rows in the first place before you try to transpose them.

Answer (score 0):

You can also write this way:

```
with open('data.txt') as inputdata:                            # open the file
  for a in inputdata:                                          # iterate through the lines of the file
    split_data = a.strip().split(',')                          # strip the line (to remove `\n` and split it using ','
    zipper = zip(element for element in split_data if element) # create the zip while keeping only non empty elements
```